# Creating file locally and copying to a remote share: Could not find this item

Tags: vb.net

I am simply trying to create a file, first in the executable's path, then copy it to a file share using the code below. The following error is returned:

> The process cannot access the file '\SERVER\Share\test.txt' because
> it is being used by another process.

We are a typical Microsoft shop running AD and the share is on our Fileserver.

I can see the file in the Debug folder, I can open it and see the contents, I can edit and save the file, but when I try to manually copy the file, just to make sure I can 'put' files in the share, I am presented with the following message:

> Could not find this item
>
> This is no longer located in ...\Debug.  Verify the item's location and try again.

I can however, copy and paste the file in the same Debug folder and successfully paste the new file to the share.

We have been running similar code for years now without issue. I don't see anything in the logs of the Anti-Virus, but I am not sure if it's Silently interfering. I assume that the created file has something screwed up about it, but I cannot identify it as I can work with the file locally.

If anyone has a direction they can point me in, I would be forever grateful for your help and will plant a tree in your name.

```
Sub Main()

        ' Source File
        Dim s As String = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), "test.txt")
        ' Destination File
        Dim d As String = "\\SERVER\Share\test.txt"
        ' content of test file
        Dim c As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        ' the file object
        Dim f As FileInfo

        Try

            ' during debugging, delete the source file if it exists
            If File.Exists(s) Then File.Delete(s)

            ' write 100 lines of text to the file
            Using sw As New StreamWriter(s)

                For i As Integer = 0 To 99
                    sw.Write(String.Format("{0}{1}", i.ToString, Environment.NewLine))
                Next

                sw.Close()

            End Using

            f = New FileInfo(s)
            f.CopyTo(d, True)

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.ReadKey()

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Create a file locally, copy the file to a file share

Comment: Apparently, I hadn't created the file before trying to write to it.  so before my the StreamWriter I put this:

Dim fi As FileStream
fi = File.Create(s)
fi.Close()
fi.Dispose()

It works now

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I hadn't created the file before trying to write to it.  so before my the StreamWriter I put this:

```
Dim fi As FileStream
fi = File.Create(s)
fi.Close()
fi.Dispose()
```

It works now